# How to open VS code terminal on Mac with PC keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code

To open the terminal you would press ctrl+˜ on PC and on Mac.

However to write tilde/backtick on Mac, using a PC keyboard, the only solution I found is to press Alt+space+n.

but trying to open the VS code terminal with ctrl+alt+space+n won't work.
Is it possible then to open that terminal with the keyboard, on Mac, using a PC keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a Mac keyboard, you can use the `^+ shortcut to open the terminal in VS Code.

If you use a PC keyboard, you may need to change the shortcut to something else that works on your PC keyboard.

To change the shortcut, you need to open Keyboard Shortcuts panel `(⌘K ⌘S or Windows+K Windows+S or View > Command Palette > Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts)` and search for `Terminal: Toggle Integrated Terminal`, and then set a new key combination.

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. : )